# jQuery Bug ? ／ The value of SVG circle in viewBox and jQuery offset method does not match

Tags: jquery, svg

**Why obtained values do not match?**

**jQuery offset method**
・top: 28.799999237060547

**Manually calculation**
・top: 28.8

Please tell me whether guided by what formula?

---

**HTML**

```
<style>
svg {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}
* {
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
   -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
        box-sizing: border-box;
}
</style>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<svg preserveAspectRatio="none" viewBox="0 0 2000 400" width="500" height="200">
  <circle id="hoge" cx="50" cy="50" r="10"/>
</svg>
<script>
  console.log($("#hoge").offset()); //Object {top: 28.799999237060547, left: 18.959999084472656}
</script>
```

---

**It does not fit formula I've tried**

28.8 = 8px (default value) + 1px(border) + (198px / 400 × 40)

・198px = 200px(SVG height) - border 1px × 2

・400px … viewBox height

・40px … 50(circle cy) - 10(circle r)

---

**Chrome Version**

44.0.2403.157 m

---

Comment: javascript maths is not accurate to an infinite number of decimal places.

Comment: instead jQury, JavaScript problem?  In this case, those of SVG is correct?

Comment: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=5856